# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: Intrinsic gas too low

Tags: contract-development

While deploying smart contract the error formed. java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: Intrinsic gas too low

Answer (score 0):

you have to allocate more gas to your transaction or in your code define your payable function if it receives ethers

e.g  `function pay(uint256 _value) payable {`